# How to solve issue with HTTP Get request

Tags: c#, frameworks, httprequest, tls1.2, .net-4.7.2

I try to run simple GET HTTP request via console application.
.NET FRAMEWORK 4.7.2
Language is C#.

```
class Program
{
    static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls /*| SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3*/;


            string versionTxtUri = "https://connect.palmbeachschools.org/version.txt";
            string versionTxtContent = _httpClient.GetStringAsync(versionTxtUri).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(versionTxtContent);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run application on WinServer2012 R2 standart I get the error

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

When I run on Windows 10 or WindowsServer 2016 Standart IT is okay. It works.

According to IISCrypto Windows Server 2012 has settings
[image]

Could you advice what I can investigate ?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare 1st request from working and non working applications.  The c# default header are different from other applications.  To fix modify the c# headers to look like working application.  The server may not support all the TLS modes.  Normally when you OR the TLS modes each mode must be tried separately.  So you first try tls 1.0 and if it fails then try tls 1.2 and finally tls1.2

Comment: Hello @jdweng 
Problem in SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake

Thanks Will investigate

Comment: Is your certificate compatible with v3 encryption?  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security.  Did code work with earlier version of Net?  There are a lot of posting with people upgrading to latest Net that SSL/TLS stopped working.  Suspect the default encryption mode changed in Net to use latest mode.  Which then code is not backwards/forward compatible.

Comment: I Compared ciphers and found out that ciphers are different

Comment: Were you able to modify?

Comment: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
 SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

I will try add these ciphers. I will let you know result. But not today

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212641/discussion-between-roman-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is add these cipher suits

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
```